# C# Formatting Long List of Numbers To Be More Compact

Tags: c#, string, formatting, output

```
Console.WriteLine("     Even Table \n");
int MaxNumber = 100;
int EvenNumbers = 0;
int i;

for (i = 0; i <=MaxNumber; i+=2)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        EvenNumbers = i;
    }
    Console.Write(EvenNumbers);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
        Even Table

0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 50 52  54 56 58 60 62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78 80 82 84 86 88 90 92 94 96 98 100
```

I am making a program that displays the even numbers between 2 and 100 inclusively. I am able to display the even numbers, although the formatting for the output is in a straight line due to the Console.Write, is there a string format that can I use to have the output display each even number, but cut to a new line every interval of 20? So it would look like:

1-20

20-40

40-60

ETC

Comment: `int threshold = 20;` and then before your `Console.Write` do `if(i % 20 == 0){Console.WriteLine(EvenNumbers)}else{Console.Write(EvenNumbers)}`

Comment: Google for `Console.Write new line` ?

Comment: What is the purpose of int threshold?

Comment: @KyleMyott , `threshold` count the numbers that are display.If this is divisible by 20,means that were already showing 20 numbers. Look at my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Comment: @KyleMyott sorry my bad, I forgot what I was doing halfway through xD, it would be used instead of `i % 20` to make it `i % threshold` because then you can use it elsewhere and edit it more easily

Comment: Yea, I thought something looked strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
for (i = 0; i <=MaxNumber; i+=2)
{
    EvenNumbers = i;
    Console.Write(EvenNumbers+" ");
    if(i%20==0){
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

You do not need condition `if (i % 2 == 0)` because your step is 2.

Comment: That worked perfectly, Thank you. Could \n also be implemented with a threshold of 20 in some way for the future?

Comment: @KyleMyott, Yes. `Console.WriteLine()` is the same with `Console.Write("\n");`

Comment: Actually, if you want a portable way to write a newline, it's `Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);`

Answer (score 2):

Less lines with `Linq!` :p

```
foreach (var even in Enumerable.Range(2, 100).Where(i => i % 2 == 0))
    Console.Write(even % 20 != 0 ? even.ToString() + " " : even.ToString() + "\n");
```

Comment: Change to this to work : `Console.Write(even % 20 != 0 ? even.ToString()+" " : even.ToString() + "\n");`

Comment: Yes! I forgot the `ToString()` at the beginning. Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution , @LuisLavieri.

Comment: Oh. Now, I understand what you meant with the formatting! Thanks @AlexandruMihai :)

Answer (score 1):

In complement for Luis solution, you can do it easily with this code :

```
foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Where(o => o % 2 == 0).GroupBy(o => (int)(o / 20.01)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", item.ToArray()));
        }
```

Loop on group by '20' filtered by modulo 2 enumeration of int and print it in one line with `string.join`
You need to cast the groupby if you want your first number are 20, 40, 60... else it starts with 22, 42, 62...

Hope this helps

Comment: It does, this is useful for more complex coding, which I need to get into rather than the simple things I am currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try below; It will consider 0 as well; Otherwise 0 will be isolated.

```
        Console.WriteLine("     Even Table \n");
        int MaxNumber = 100;
        int EvenNumbers = 0;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= MaxNumber; i += 2)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                EvenNumbers = i;
            }

            Console.Write(" ");
            Console.Write(EvenNumbers);
            if (i % 20 == 0 && i>0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach using [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int MaxNumber = 100;

// create a list of all even numbers
List<int> even_list = Enumerable.Range(0, MaxNumber+1).Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList();

// for the amount of numbers to be displayed in a line
int numbers_in_single_line = 10
for (int i = 1; i <= even_list.Count; i += numbers_in_single_line)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", even_list.Skip(i).Take(numbers_in_single_line )));
}
```

[`Skip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) allow you to select values from the list at certain positions